# .htaccess url aliasing for /r/var to #/r/var

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried going through the documentation for this but I'm definitely no sys admin. I'd like to create a ReWrite rule for my domain alienstream.com, so that `alienstream.com/r/electronicmusic` is aliased to `alienstream.com/#r/electronicmusic`

I know what the general form is going to follow

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /#/?var=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but I just don't understand the syntax for this

Comment: I am unsure how redirecting to a hash would handle in a .htaccess, as # is used for single line comments in .htaccess files.

Comment: @ir-g I would be fine with http://alienstream.com?sub=/r/electronicmusic if that's all that's possible

Comment: Do you want a redirect or an rewrite rule.

Comment: @ir-g I would ideally like them to see just alienstream.com/r/electronicmusic like how reddit works so I believe that falls under rewrite

Comment: Would this be a the case for every item? Like(/r/* =  ?sub=r/*)

Comment: @ir-g yup, every /r/, if it doesn't exist I'll deal with it clientside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(r/.+?)/?$ /?sub=$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: I have corrected the rule to work as intended, hashes are not possible and result in %23, even when escaped

Comment: Did you try: `RewriteRule ^(r/.+?)/?$ /#$1 [NC,L,R,NE]` ?

Comment: I did try the originally suggested RewriteRule ^(r/.+?)/?$ /#$1 [NC,L,R]
 and it failed resulting in http://alienstream.com/%23r/dubstep